# JQuery Find <option> tag by it value in <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select name="InputSource"  class="required page_basic" style="margin-left:23%" form="broadcastform" >

        <option value="">Broadcast Input</option>             
        <option value="0">HDMIPhy</option>             
        <option value="1">USB Streaming</option>             
        <option value="2">MPEC-TS Interface</option>             
        <option value="3">VIP(Ethernet)</option>         

</select>
```

So Basically, I'm trying to find its text by its value. e.g if value = 0 its return me "HDMIPhy".

So this select tag is the 4th tag in the "form" tag. This is what I tried.

```
$("select:nth-child(4), #someid").text()
```

but somehow I dont want to give all option tag an unique id which will be exhausted. Is it possible to get it by its value? Also, the 1st,2nd,3rd tag in form tag is not select. Is it possible to get like only select for the form which means 1st select tag in my case. Anyone has idea bout it?

Comment: you want the value for which one selected

Comment: [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: If you intend using jQuery in your projects, please take a few minutes to browse through the [complete list of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). There aren't that many, and in future you'll have a better idea of how to get jQuery to do stuff. (Or even browse through the [list of all methods *and* selectors](http://api.jquery.com/).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an attribute selector:

```
$("select[name='InputSource'] option[value='0']").text(); //"HDMIPhy"
```

Or if you have a variabls:

```
$("select[name='" + resul‌​t[i].name + "'] option[value='" + result[‌​i].value + "']").text();
```

Comment: But in my case. I have a json array which is the result of my form. Can it be used like this $("select[name=result[i].name] option[value=result[i].value]").text(); it looks a lil bit wired tho.

Comment: `$("select[name='" + resul‌​t[i].name + "'] option[value='" + result[‌​i].value + "']").text();`

Comment: content += '<tr>'+'<td>' +  result[i].name + '</td>'+'<td>' +  $("select[name='" + resul‌​t[i].name + "'] option[value='" + result[‌​i].value + "']").text() + '</td>'+'</tr>';

Comment: it said there is bug in it. i dont see no bug in it. what just happened

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on order and count of elements. Rely on what these elements are.
If you don't want to use IDs, you can use input names instead:

```js
function displaySelectText(selectName, optionValue) {
  var $select = $("select[name='" + selectName + "']");
  var $option = $select.find("option[value='" + optionValue + "']");
  
  return $option.text();
}

console.log(displaySelectText("InputSource", "3"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="InputSource">
  <option value="">Broadcast Input</option>             
  <option value="0">HDMIPhy</option>             
  <option value="1">USB Streaming</option>             
  <option value="2">MPEC-TS Interface</option>             
  <option value="3">VIP(Ethernet)</option>         
</select>
```

Comment: $("select[name='" + selectName + "']"); is this the right syntax? coz the console keep telling me that a syntax error.

Comment: alert($( "select[name='" + resul‌​t[0].name + "'] option:selected" ).text()); it said this is an syntax error within

Comment: @Pawan It is correct and it works for me. You have some sort of invisible symbol in your keyword. It is actually not `result[0]`, but `resul&zwnj;&#8203;t[0]`. I cannot say why it happened, but you can simply remove this word and type it in again.

Comment: var result = $('#broadcastform').serializeArray();
           var content = "<table>";
           alert(resul‌​t[2].name );
           for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
            if(result[i].name=="InputSource"){
             var res = 1;
            content += '<tr>'+'<td>' +  result[i].name + '</td>'+'<td>' + '1' + '</td>'+'</tr>';

            }
            else
              content += '<tr>'+'<td>' +  result[i].name + '</td>'+'<td>' +  result[i].value + '</td>'+'</tr>';
           }

Comment: its so weird that it said alert(resul‌​t[2].n‌​ame ); a syntax error. but things work fine with result[i].name below

Comment: @Pawan And again, you have some invisible symbols in your code. `its so weird that it said alert(resul&zwnj;&#8203;t[2].n&zwnj;&zwnj;&#8203;&#8203;ame ); a syntax error. but things work fine with result[i].name below`. Probably, you copy the code from a corrupted source or use a broken text editor.

Comment: god. im so confused now. I just wanna make the form result at the end page. shows up the pair before user submit. and replace the value with the text. and it took me whole afternoon :(.

Comment: i finally got you sir. I type the "result" again. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **already value set** then you can get selected text by simply:

```
var itemText = $("select[name='InputSource'] option:selected").text();
console.log(itemText);
```

If your **value not set** and you wants static then you can get by:

```
var itemText = $("select[name='InputSource'] option[value='1']").text();
console.log(itemText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, you can also use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
var x = $('select[name="InputSource"] > option').filter(function(index, element){
        return $(element).val() == "1";
    }).text();

alert(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="InputSource"  class="required page_basic" style="margin-left:23%" form="broadcastform" >

        <option value="">Broadcast Input</option>             
        <option value="0">HDMIPhy</option>             
        <option value="1">USB Streaming</option>             
        <option value="2">MPEC-TS Interface</option>             
        <option value="3">VIP(Ethernet)</option>         

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```